# How to place a Icon inside textinput in react native

Tags: react-native, icons

I have app in react native.In my app, I have two textinput , i want to set icon inside textinput.Icon can be any react native vector icons,especially "marker" or "location marker"..Can anyone tell me how to do that??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) as you can render it inside a text component. But if you want to use it as if it were inside a TextInput you have to wrap Icon and TextInput inside a View:

```
<View>
  <Icon ... />
  <TextInput ... />
</View>
```

Then you can do something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked..not inside of textinput but that's okay...thanku for your time and help..